# Adding comma-separated numbers to Javascript output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following JS code for a timer:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.timer').countTo({
        from: 2046430,
        to: 2048503,
        speed: 3050000,
        refreshInterval: 50,
        onComplete: function(value) {
            console.debug(this);
        }
    });
});
```

How do I add commas to "2046430" so it looks like "2,046,430"?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have got the answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: Are you looking to format the numbers for output, or to format the numbers differently in your code?

Answer (score 3):

simply use java-script method

```
var num = 2046430; 
num.toLocaleString();

will give you "2,046,430"
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in Safari, where it will return the same result as regular `toString()`.

Comment: i don't hav IOS and never tested on it before, kindly ensure if this is. Thanks